# Excel VBA Change Value in another column and row in range

Tags: excel, vba

I have problem in my code, i need to change in another column - row

I tried to built macro but it's dosn't work with that.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim xRg As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set xRg = Intersect(Target, Range("A6:U1000"))

If xRg Is "YES" Then Exit Sub
Range("G" & Target.Row).Value = "CHECK"
End Sub
```

When in column N6:N1000 is "YES" in Column G change value to "Check" and all row A6 for example to U1000 is in color red

Comment: Please, delete line `On Error Resume Next` because it *hides* errors, but they still occur, and execute your code.

Comment: Currently the code will `Exit Sub` once a value of `YES` is encountered. Should that read `<> "YES"`

Comment: Is Mismatch, but i don't know how to repair this

Comment: `If xRg.Value = "YES" Then Exit Sub` Is this what you are trying? Also since you are working with `Worksheet_Change`, you may want to se [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure/13861640#13861640)

Comment: Yes @SiddharthRout i'm trying to do this but it's doesn't work with that. Is mismatch error -13

Comment: You have to use `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A6:U1000")) Is Nothing Then`. Please once again read the link that I gave above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't quite understand what you're trying to achieve here, but hopefully the below will be doing roughly what you need. Try it and let me know if it doesn't behave the way you hope.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim xRg As Range, cl as Range
    Set xRg = Intersect(Target, Range("A6:U1000"))
    If Not xRg Is Nothing Then
        For Each cl In xRg.Cells
            If cl.Value = "YES" Then Range("G" & cl.Row).Value = "CHECK"
        Next
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```